# Schedule using "at" CMD in LOOP

Tags: for-loop, cmd, at-job

I want to defrag disks remotely. I tried this short script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in (servers.txt) do (
at \\%%s 20:00 defrag.exe c: -f
)
@pause
```

Normally others command work e.g. `ping %%s`. Unfortunately when I use "`at`" command that doesn't work (The command "loops" on first server and after that CMD window closes).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: according to "at /?" shouldn't you use \\%%s ?

Comment: but why ? this is only variable... i think... correct me if im wrong.

Comment: now i see...my mistake... but when i use \\%%s that not working too....

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `defrag.exe c: -f` should be in quotes.

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in (servers.txt) do (
at \\%%s 20:00 "defrag.exe c: -f" ) 
@pause
```